# Retrieving partial object

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, is it possible to retrieve a slice of an object which includes only fields whose values satisfy a certain clause? For example, for

```
{terms: {a: 1, :b: 2, c: 10}}
```

I'd like to get only the fields in `terms` whose values are less than 10, getting

```
{terms: {a: 1, :b 2}}
```

I know I can model my records as following:

```
{terms: [{term:'a', value:1}, {term:'b', value:2}]}
```

and then retrieve only the `terms` less than 10 using the following query:

```
db.coll.find({}, {terms: {$elemMatch: {value: {$lt: 10}}}});
```

but I am looking for a more space-efficient way to store the data (I've got LOTS of those elements).

Comment: No, you can't do queries on arbitrary fields like that (and thus you cannot retrieve just a slice either). Field names must be declared as part of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such query-projection feature in MongoDB.